# how to work with directory in php

Tags: php

the code is

```
<?php
$files = array();  
$dir = opendir('/xampp/htdocs/myfun/template/home');  
while(($file = readdir($dir)) !== false) {
    if($file !== '.' && $file !== '..') {  
        $files[] = $file;
    }
}  
closedir($dir);  
//sort($files);
$i=0; 
foreach($files as $key) {
    echo "<iframe align='center' width='100%' height='605px' src='$key' title='$files[$i]'></iframe>";
    break;
}
?>
```

i want to show templates onclick  next/prev button.horizontally.
like slider.
please help

Comment: You need to learn, how to work with arrays first I think. You not incrase `$i`, but you do not need, because `$key` (what is actually `$value`) will be the file name. And you do not need to use `foreach` if you break at the first iteration.

Answer (score 0):

Correct logic to iterate a directory in while loop is **false != ($file = readdir($dir))**, where you assign file name first and check it's not false.

Also you can print title with $key itself. $files[$i] and $i variable is not required.

In order to iterate through all files of directory remove break, this will cause to end the loop after first iteration.

```
<?php
$files = array();
$dir = opendir('/xampp/htdocs/myfun/template/home');
while(false != ($file = readdir($dir)))
{
    if($file !== '.' && $file !== '..')
    {
        $files[] = $file;
    }
}
closedir($dir);
//sort($files);

foreach($files as $key)
{
    echo "<iframe align='center' width='100%' height='605px' src='$key' title='$key'></iframe>";
}
?>
```